# Error:Property font is read-only in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, readonly

I am really getting out of control with this small problem and unable to rectify it?

Can anyone help me in this!

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim installed_fonts As New InstalledFontCollection
    lstFont.Items.Clear()
    For Each font_family As FontFamily In installed_fonts.Families
        lstFont.Items.Add(font_family.Name)
    Next font_family
    lstFont.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

 Private Sub txtSize_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSize.TextChanged, chkBold.Click, chkItalic.Click, chkUnderline.Click, chkStrikeout.Click, lstFont.SelectedIndexChanged
        ShowSample()
    End Sub
```

Private Sub ShowSample()

```
' Compose the font style.
Dim font_style As FontStyle = FontStyle.Regular
If Bold.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Bold
If Italic.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Italic
If Underline.Checked Then font_style = font_style Or FontStyle.Underline


' Get the font size.
Dim font_size As Single = 8
Try
    font_size = Single.Parse(DropFontSize.SelectedValue)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try

' Get the font family name.
Dim family_name As String = DropFont.SelectedIndex.ToString
If Not (DropFont.SelectedItem Is Nothing) Then
    family_name = DropFont.SelectedItem.ToString
End If
' Make the new font.
Dim new_font As New Font( _
    family_name, font_size, font_style)

' Set the sample's font.
TextBox1.Font.Name = new_font.Name
TextBox1.Font.Size = font_size
TextBox1.Font.Bold = Bold.Checked
TextBox1.Font.Italic = Italic.Checked
TextBox1.Font.Underline = Underline.Checked
```

End Sub

I am getting as Property font is read-only and I have tried many snippets to get rid of this problem but none worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set like below, [WebControl.Font Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.font.aspx) is read only

```
Private Sub ShowSample()
    .....
    Dim new_font As New Font( _
        family_name, font_size, font_style)

    ' Set the sample's font.
    txtSample.Font.Name = new_font.Name
    txtSample.Font.Size = Font.Size
    txtSample.Font.Bold = chkBold.Checked
    txtSample.Font.Italic = chkItalic.Checked
    txtSample.Font.Underline = chkUnderline.Checked
    txtSample.Font.Strikeout= chkStrikeout.Checked

End Sub
```

Comment: Though I have updated my code with yours it's not showing me any difference.

Comment: set `AutoPostBack="true"` for txtSample in aspx page

Answer (score 0):

Because the property *is* read-only, as per the [definition from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.font.aspx#Y120):

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property Font As FontInfo
Get
```

You will need to set the properties of `Font`, such as `Name`.

```
txtSample.Font.Name = new_font.Name
```

Comment: If I set this way txtSample.Font.Name = new_font.size and txtSample.Font.size = new_font.Name for style there is no property such as txtsample.font.style. so how do I set for that?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the style property? There is a Style property directly on the control (i.e. txtSample.Style) but this is used to set CSS properties.